# Nodejs Net Data event listener To wait for the right data

Tags: node.js, tcpclient, tcpserver

I have a tcp client that receives defined message types from a server
When the client writes it passes an identifier that comes with the message from the server in response to this.
The data event listener should do something like this

```
sock.on('data', function (data) {
      //validate the data, check if identifier == to identifier in data
      if(true){
        return data
        //terminate listener
     }
     else{
       // wait for the next message
       // this should also exit upon a time out and terminate listener
     }
  });
```

How can i wait for the exact one after checking the data since several messages are written to the same socket for other listeners. After 4 seconds i want to exit even if the data in socket does not match the identifier

Please help.

Comment: what is the identifier for ? is it unique for each data returned or is it identifier of client-server connection ?

Comment: @Aky_0788 these messages represent transactions that have a unique identifier known by both the client side and the server side.

Answer (score 0):

```
      // initialize the expected  message identifier
      let expected = outgoing.getMti() 
      client.on('data', function (data) {
                //get the message identifier from data
                let incomingMTI = data.getMti()
                switch(incomingMTI){
                    case expected:
                        resolve (data)
                    default:
                        if((Date.now()-start)>8000){
                            reject({error:'timed out'})
                        }
                }
            });
```

So far i think the listener times out after 8 seconds. and send the error message. 
If you have a better way or see something i didn't please :-)